# С#Afforge VideoPlayer проигрывание картинки

Tags: c#

Можно ли используя Afforge проигрывать в его плеере одну картинку, взятую из jpeg-файла без формирования видеофайлов с помощью класса VideoFileWriter  ffmpeg библиотеки?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile( "test.jpg" );
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду поставить это в Videosource для плеера?

Comment: Если покажете свой код, то я смогу дать более точный ответ, но это не точно =)